# are they not subspace , even if trivial?

Tags: linear-algebra

1. $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2=0, x,y\in\mathbb{C}\}$, is it a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$?

I thought yes atleast a trivial subspace as $\{(0,0)\}$ , the answer says No!

2. $\{(x,y): x^2-y^2=0, x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$, is it a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I thought yes as it is  just $y=x$ or $y=-x$ so one dimensional subspace of the plane, but answer says No!

3.$\{(x,y): xy=0, x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$, is it a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I thought yes atleast a trivial subspace as $\{(0,0)\}$ , the answer says No!

please help

Comment: Subspace as what? Complex vector space? Real vector space? Qational vector space? Topological space? Metric space? Banach space? Complex Hilbert space?

Comment: Given the linear algebra tag and lack of other tags, I think it's safe to assume subspace of the vector space given over the field implied by the vector space. But correct me if I'm wrong OP.

Comment: The space in question (1) is not $\{(0,0)\}$. For example $(1,i)$ is in that set.

Comment: You seem to be missing an important part of the definition of subspace in question (2). Hint: If two different lines are in a subspace, then their common plane is in the subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first and third parts, there are solutions that aren't $(0,0)$, and these solutions are not closed under addition.  Note that $(1, i)$ and $(1, -i)$ both satisfy $x^2+y^2 = 0$ but the sum $(2,0)$ does not.  Also, note that $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ satisfy $xy = 0$ but the sum $(1,1)$ does not.

For the second one, you have successfully identified the subset as a union of two lines.  However, such a union is not closed under addition, either.  For instance $(1,1)$ lies on $y = x$ and $(1,-1)$ lies on $y = -x$, but the sum $(2,0)$ lies on neither line.

Answer (score 2):

For $1$ you have that $(1,i)$ and $(1,-i)$ are in the set but $(2,0)=(1,i)+(1,-i)$ is not. Hence it is not a subspace.

For $2$ it is similar. Use $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

For 1, notice that $x^2+y^2=0$ has the *Complex* solution $x= \pm iy$, not just the Real solution $(0,0)$

For2), notice that $x= \pm y$ is a collection of the two lines $y=x, y=-x$. Can you add points in the two lines and remain in the union of the two lines?

For
3)Notice that $xy=0$ has solutions $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$, for any nonzero $a,b$.